# How to open view after messageBox click ok using extjs?

Tags: extjs4.2

```
var myWindow = Ext.Msg.show({
    title: "Registration Revert",
    message: "Registration successful",
    buttonText: { ok: 'OK'},
    fn: function (btn) {
        if (btn == 'ok') {
              console.log('recieve');
              me.fireEvent('afterRegister');
          }

    }
});
```

How to open view after messageBox click ok using extjs?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var myWindow = Ext.Msg.show({
title: "Registration Revert",
message: "Registration successful",
buttonText: { ok: 'OK'},
fn: function (btn) {
    if (btn == 'ok') {
          console.log('recieve');
          Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyWindow').show(); // Give your app name and View name according to your application
      }

}
```

});